# Calling Methods and Using Proper Loops

Tags: java, loops, methods, while-loop, call

I am creating a program that basically asks a user what they wish to purchase and gives them their total.

I am supposed to use 2 separate methods outside of Main to complete this task:

1. One method to get the user input as to which service they want performed, this method will also tell the user the total cost of the services (BEFORE TAX AND LABOR)
2. Another method to calculate labor costs and tax costs

The first method should return total cost to the main method, and the second method should get that total from the main method and calculate the Final Cost after labor and tax are added in.

(if the car is an import, 5% of the total should be added on)

Here is what I have so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Assign3 {

    public static double carMaintenance(String userCar) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        String service_ordered="";
        String more="yes";
        double amount;
        double total=0;
        //declare and intialize parallel arrays, Services and Prices and display them to the user
        String[] services = {"Oil Change" , "Tire Rotation", "Air Filter", "Fluid Check"}; //intialize list of services
        double[]price = {39.99, 49.99, 19.99, 10.99}; //initialize corresponding price for services
        for(int i= 0; i < services.length; i++) {
            System.out.print( services[i]+ "...." );    
            System.out.print( price[i] + "\t");  
        }

        do // *****2. THIS IS WHAT IS BEING EXECUTED FROM THE METHOD CALL IN MAIN *****
        {
            System.out.print("What service do you want done?: ");
            String choice = input.nextLine();
            if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("oil change")) {
                System.out.println("You chose an oil change");
                amount = 39.99;
                total = total + amount;
                service_ordered+="Oil Change ";
                System.out.print("Do you want to do another service? ");
                more = input.nextLine();
            } else if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("tire rotation")) {
                System.out.println("You chose a tire rotation");
                amount = 49.99;
                total = total + amount;
                service_ordered+="Tire Rotation ";
                System.out.print("Do you want to do another service? ");
                more = input.nextLine();
            } else if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("air filter")) {
                System.out.println("You chose an air filter");
                amount = 19.99;
                total = total + amount;
                service_ordered+="Air Filter ";
                System.out.print("Do you want to do another service? ");
                more = input.nextLine();
            } else if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("fluid check")) {
                System.out.println("You chose a flud check");
                amount = 10.99;
                total = total + amount;
                service_ordered+="Fluid Check ";
                System.out.print("Do you want to do another service? ");
                more = input.nextLine();
            } 
        } while (more.equalsIgnoreCase("yes"));
        System.out.println("You ordered: " + service_ordered);
        System.out.println("Your total due is " + total);

        return total;
    }

    public static void main(String[]args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("What kind of car do you have?: "); //****1. CODE STARTS HERE *****
        String userCar = input.nextLine();


        double total = carMaintenance(userCar); //*****2. CODE CALLS THIS METHOD AND EXECUTES IT *****

        calcFinalPrice(total);
    }

    public static void calcFinalPrice(double total) {

        double salesTax=.08;
        double laborFee=.3;
        double importFee=.05;

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Is your vehicle an import?: "); 
        String isImport = input.nextLine();
        if(isImport.equals("yes")) {
            total=total*laborFee+total;  // this is the labor fee
            double importTotal = total*importFee+total;
            double totalAfterTax = importTotal*salesTax+importTotal;    //this is the import total aftertax
            System.out.println("It will cost " + totalAfterTax + " to fix your vehicle.");
        }

        if(isImport.equals("no")) {
            total=total*laborFee+total;  // this is the labor fee
            double totalAfterTax = total*salesTax+total;    //this is the total aftertax
            System.out.println("It will cost " + totalAfterTax + " to fix your vehicle ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, considering your code works so far, you need to change the carMaintenance declaration from `public static void` to `public static double` and put a `return total;` in the last line of the function. In main() you do something like `double total = carMaintenance(userCar);` and then `calcFinalPrice(total);`. That function should then be `public static void calcFinalPrice(double total)` and you should remove the `double total = 0;` line. You're almost there...

Comment: I'm still having trouble getting the code to tell me the final price after the taxes are factored in.
I'm positive its because I'm not calling the method properly...how do i properly call the calcFinalPrice method in main to get it to display?

Comment: It's all in my previous comment. Update your question with your source after you made the changes I advised and then I'll have another look.

Comment: Okay, I Updated it

Comment: As it looks you only need to add `calcFinalPrice(total);` to your main().

Comment: adding calcFinalPrice(total); helped. Although the calculations were incorrect. I will see what I did wrong there.

My only other problem is that the code is executing the carMaintenance method twice.

I updated the code with comments for clarity.

Comment: Yes, of course it executes `carMaintenance` twice. After all, you are calling it twice. Remove it from `calcFinalPrice()` (second line in that function)

Comment: Final question! 

When my code is fully executed, the final line reads "It wil cost xx.xxx to fix your vehicle"

I want to replace the word vehicle with the user input from the main method when the user is asked "What kind of car do you have" (userCar) 

I know I should know this but im burned out.

Comment: You can either make `userCar` (defined in main) a global variable and use that, or pass the userCar variable on to calcFinalPrice. Another way (and I would prefer this) is to let your functions only do what the name says, so have calcFinalPrice return the final price back to `main()` (you show know how by now?) and print the message in `main()` using userCar.

Comment: I tried return totalAfterTax; within the calcFinalPrice() method and then tried calling it within the main() method using totalAfterTax = calcFinalPrice(total);    to no avail... not sure how to do what you suggested.

Comment: Two things to consider: You declare double totalAfterTax inside the scope of the if-conditions, so it won't be available outside. Did you declare it in the scope of the method first? Secondly: did you change `public static void` to `public static double`? If so, it should work. Please update your code if it doesn't.

Comment: You are a genius. Thank you so much for your help. It is now doing exactly what I want it to do thanks to your advice.